# Installing libspatialindex on Windows 8

Tags: python, installation, windows-8, rtree

I need to use Rtrees to make some code I'm running faster. However, in order to use Rtree, I need to install libspatialindex. When I've installed packages in the past I've been able to either download a .exe file from Chris Gohlke's site, or use `setup.py install` from the command prompt, after extracting the contents of a tar.gz file.

The problem I'm having is that 1.) There is no .exe file on Gohlke's site, and 2.) After downloading 'spatialindex-src-1.8.4.tar', and trying to extract it, I get the error 'Can not create output directory' - I have no idea what that's all about. 3.) I go to http://download.osgeo.org/libspatialindex/ and download the appropriate file - i.e.  libspatialindex-1.8.1-win-msvc-2010-x64-x32.zip, when I unzip it seems obvious that everything I need is there - there are a number of .dll files. It seems like this last one is the best route, but after unzipping, I don't know what to do with all the files. Do they need to do into my DLLs folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really sure but libspatialindex is only a C library (low level).

You should just need to use the [Rtree Windows installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rtree), a Python package using libspatialindex on the top.

In fact, since we answered, the install process has changed.
You need to get a remote URL to a file ending with `.whl` (for "wheel", a new Python packaging way to ease installation) or you can download the file and install from it.

Then, you will do from command line:

```
# Install from remote ressource
pip install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/djcobkfp/Rtree-0.8.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
# Or for local downloaded file
pip install Rtree-0.8.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

We know what we are installing because of file name convention:

- `Rtree-0.8.2` = Rtree version 0.8.2
- `cp27-cp27m` = Version of Python = 2.7
- `win_amd64` = Windows 64 bits architecture

For installation, you can also use [this page](http://toblerity.org/rtree/install.html#windows) from official docs.

Comment: When I run `set.py install` for the Rtree module from my command prompt, I get `could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll`, so I was assuming I needed to install it. I have a files called `spatialindex_c-32.dll` that came with my 'libspatialindex-1.8.1-win-msvc-2010-x64-x32.zip' download. I was thinking maybe I just need to put is where the installer is looking?

Comment: Why did you not download the RTree installer in the first link? It's a Windows installer. I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks! I saw in the documentation that you first need to install libspatialindex. So, naturally I tried installing that first - but to no avail. And, on the Rtree site they offer the tar ball for install, so I tried to go through that in the command prompt, which threw my the error listed abover. I ended up going to the Gohlke site and all appears to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the installation with conda instead of pip.

`conda install -c conda-forge cenpy`

See the CenPy documentation: https://pypi.org/project/cenpy/

You don't need to separately install geopandas and Rtree if you use conda.