# Installing Rtree on Windows 7 Python 35

Tags: python, windows-7, rtree

I tried installing Rtree on Python35 on my windows 7 machine using the pip install command but ran into this error:
*OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll*

I also tried this and it gave me the same error:
    C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\easy_install.exe Rtree

I looked up this post on StackExchange:
[Installing libspatialindex on Windows 8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120527/installing-libspatialindex-on-windows-8/120530#120530)

However, I am not able to find a binary for Python35. Can you please tell me how to go about installing Rtree?