# Selecting polygons which contain at least one point with spatial index using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, overlapping-features, select-by-location, point-in-polygon, spatial-index

I have a points shapefile and a polygon shapefile. I would like to select all the polygons which have at least one point in them.

The problem I'm running into is how long this takes. I have 1 million points and about 320,000 polygons, so using spatial query takes far too long. I've heard that I'd need to write a Python script with spatial indexing to get a feasibly quick result, but I have no idea how to approach this.

I don't mind if it's a little inaccurate if it runs significantly quicker.

What I've tried to cobble together from other stack overflow questions is:

```
pointProvider = self.pointLayer.dataProvider()
all_point = pointProvider.getFeatures()
delta = 0.1

for point in all_point:

    searchRectangle = QgsRectangle(point.x() - delta, point.y()  - delta, point.x() + delta, point.y() + delta)

    candidateIDs = line_index.intesects(searchRectangle)

    for candidateID in candidateIDs:
        candFeature == rotateProvider.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(candidateID)).next()
        if candFeature.geometry().contains(point):
        
            break
```

This throws up a NameError:

> name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @JoshuaKidd! Remove `self`, you don't really need this in a script. Also take a look at [Using a QGIS spatial index to speed up your code](https://nathanw.net/2013/01/04/using-a-qgis-spatial-index-to-speed-up-your-code/) which may be helpful :)

Comment: Thank you! If what I've written works, what should I replace self with? I can see in the example you posted that he finds if features in a single vector layer touch another. I'm guessing if I try and adapt what he's written I'll have to find a way to see if a point from one layer overlaps a vector in another.

Comment: If you have acces to GeoPandas Python module, it could be very straightforward to do that with 'sjoin' method and 'intersects' option (see my answer).

Comment: @JoshuaKidd -No need to replace `self`, just remove it. In terms of the example link I posted, you could replace `touches` with `intersects`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have taken a rollback according to the needs of [@Joshua Kidd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/89874/joshua-kidd), which was looking for the fastest (and not the most correct) solution.

The code posted in the following will select a polygon feature when its bounding box contains at least one point. Instead, the most correct solution (i.e. the selection of a polygon feature when its real geometry contains at least one point) is reported at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/224954/4) previous revision of my answer.

The fastest solution I could apply in PyQGIS would be this one:

```py
##Points=vector point
##Polygons=vector polygon

from qgis.core import *
import processing

layer1 = processing.getObject(Points)
layer2 = processing.getObject(Polygons)

index = QgsSpatialIndex() # Spatial index
for ft in layer1.getFeatures():
    index.insertFeature(ft)

selection = [] # This list stores the features which contains at least one point
for feat in layer2.getFeatures():
    inGeom = feat.geometry()
    idsList = index.intersects(inGeom.boundingBox())
    if idsList:
        selection.append(feat)

# Select all the polygon features which contains at least one point
layer2.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])
```

Starting from this sample layers:

[image]

and running the above code, I obtain this output:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error saying processing not defined.

Comment: That's weird.. Try typing `import processing` at the top of the code. However, I need to edit  it because at this moment it selects all the polygons for which the **bounding box** contains a point (it's a minor fix, I'll edit the answer as soon as possible, sorry)

Comment: I just added 'import processing' and it's running now :)

Comment: WOW, that ran in 40 seconds as opposed to my previous best 16 min!

Comment: Well! I edited the code, now it should work as expected! Please, let me know if it works for you! =)

Comment: I'm running your updated code and it's a bit slower now, it's up to 7 minutes.
Is there any way to just make the bounding box trivially small?

Comment: As far as I know the bounding box can't be handled in other ways. However, please test my edited code: by now there is a `pass` if there was already one intersection for the current feature, so it should avoid iterating over all the ids taken from the `idsList` list (it should consider only the first intersecting one, and the pass to the next polygon feature). Please, let me know if it is faster by now.

Comment: I'm running it now, it's taken 9 minutes so far. I crashed out the last one after it ran for 20 minutes.
Could you possibly post the first script you wrote? It may be good enough for my purposes, I'll have to run it a few hundred times. I really appreciate all your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51996/discussion-between-howtoinqgis-and-joshua-kidd).

Comment: As a further question, if I wanted to loop this for several layers of points, is there an easy way to change

 layer2.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])

to add to selection instead?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Assuming looping over several point layers, do you want to refresh the selection for each point layer or do you want to "aggregate" your selection for having a final selection which consider the poylgon features intersected by any point layer? I think it is possible to modify the code, but I think it should be a new question.

Comment: I was hoping to aggregate. I've got it working fine I think though, I looped it so it doesn't reset the 'selection' list, and at the end it sets the selected features.

Comment: Well, if you want to aggregate it's probably sufficient adding a loop immediately after the line `selection = []`, inserting a new line for the iteration of point layers (something like `for lyr in lyrs`, where `lyrs` is a selection of your point layers).

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the GeoPandas Python module, it could be very straightforward to do that with [`sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html#geopandas-sjoin) method and *'intersects'* option. I tried out my approach with the next situation:

[image]

The code was:

```py
from geopandas import gpd 

points = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/random_points.shp')  
polys = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp') 
polyWithPoints = gpd.sjoin(polys, points, op='intersects') 

polyWithPoints.to_file('/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polyWithPoints.shp')
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, I loaded the resulting shapefile (polyWithPoints.shp) and it was as expected: all the polygons (blue color) that have at least one point in them:

[image]

Comment: Alright, I'll give this a try. I'm just installing geopandas now. My main problem isn't that I can't get it to select the features, it's that I'm looking for the quickest way to do it. Does this method use spatial indexing, or something similar?

Comment: Yes, it does.  So, you also need Rtree python module (in my case installed with easy_install) and libspatialindex library (from my Debian Linux repository). If you are Windows user see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120527/installing-libspatialindex-on-windows-8

Comment: hmmm, this geopandas install is more involved than I thought. I'm using spyder through anaconda

Comment: I use GNU/Debian Linux where installation of these libraries are much easier.

Comment: Ok, i got it working, and it ran for 16 minutes which is good. A problem though, is that it creates entries for each point in a poly.