# Selecting one polygon for one point using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a points shapefile and a polygon shapefile. I work in ArcGIS Pro.

I would like to select all the polygons which have one or more points in them, however, one condition should be considered, that if one point lies in two or more polygons which overlays, only one polygon is selected.

Please see picture for example. There are 3 polygons highlighted with orange circle with only one point in them. As the polygons overlay, the result I obtained from ArcGIS Summarize Within tool showed that each of these polygons consist of one point, which is wrong, cause there are not 3 points, but 1. There should be only one polygon with one point, the other one stays empty.

[image]

The result should look something like this. Orange points are selected polygons with one or more points. And pay attention to black line - these are polygons which overlays and shares a point, but only one of them are selected. Of course this could be done manually, but it's too time consuming and it gets hard when there are to many overlaying polygons, so I try to find a fast way to do this.

[image]

Here is a very similar question [Selecting polygons which contain at least one point with spatial index](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224930/selecting-polygons-which-contain-at-least-one-point-with-spatial-index) about at least one and more points in polygon, but the solution selects all polygons with intersection, even if they overlay and share a common point.

I couldn't find the solution with "Join attributes by location" or "Select attributes by location". I'm probably missing something and this should be done easily.

Is there some fast and effective way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. By specifying multiple software sracks, you are in effect asking multiple questions. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on one solution.

Comment: Answer can be found https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389813/polygons-which-overlays-and-shares-a-point-only-one-of-them-should-be-selected by radouxju.
Solution works.